# Make sure objects not deleted in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

In a iOS application where I don't use storry boards, I am done with all initializing and is about to move on to the actuall application. My first page is a simple status page that had all the initilizing of database and so on with feedback to the user of whats going on.

My idea is to create a small control object where I can create the pages and keep track of the changes. This will be the core that will recive most of the events, however I don't know where I shall put the reference to that object so its not automatcally cleaned. The object will not be a view in it selv as it will create the views on demand.

Can I store it in implementation of the view I left or will that be disposed of as soon as I create new views to replace it? If not, can I backtrack to the `UIApplicationMain` and store it there?

I am just afraid that the iOS suddenly shall think the object is not referenced and remove it.

**Edit:**
Maybe I am uncleare, but basically what I want is something like this:

In original view, create a object and run `[myControl RunApplication]`. In `RunApplication`I create the page handler and the views. Then this function end as the application is set up, but the views will have events back to `myControl` that will respond to creating new views, destroing views and so on. Its `myControl` that I am afraid that iOS will kill for me unless I save a reference somewhere.

I have done programming for 30 years, but I am rather new to iOS coding and might miss the hole point in how iSO works.

Comment: control your code changes , or Tracking the app  ???

Comment: Thanks. Edited in an atempt to make my self a bit more clear in what I ask for.

Comment: 'I am just afraid that the iOS suddenly shall think the object is not referenced and remove it.' this will not happen. IOS doesn't have garbage collector. All objects live cycle is determined by programmer.

Comment: @Cy-4AH: Whats all about the Automatic Reference Counter then?

Comment: As I said, determined by programmer, IOS will not delete objects **suddenly**.